# jQuery removeAttr('selected') doesn't change the view

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have a multi-select form.

And I am doing the following via jQuery to "unselect" all the options.

```
$('#select').find('option').attr('selected', false);
```

Programmatically, it works. However, on the actual page, the option is still highlighted in GREY.

BUT, when I scroll down until that option is not visible and then scroll back up, the grey-highlighting is gone. I'm using Chrome.

I checked it in Firefox, and it works fine. Is this a Chrome bug?

Answer (score 4):

Try setting it to the default value.

```
$('#select').val("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Could also try:

```
$('#select').find('option').removeAttr('selected');
```